# "Invalid syntax" when calling python code using "sudo python main.py" but not using "python main.py"

Tags: debian, sudo

I have this piece of code

```py
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Europe/Copenhagen"))
log_name = f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))}/logs/main/{now.strftime(format='%Y-%m-%d')}.log" #Create path for log
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_name,filemode="a",level = logging.INFO,format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

which works fine when running `python main.py`. But, if I run it as sudo, i.e `sudo python main.py` I get this error

```
 File "main.py", line 28
    log_name = f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))}/logs/main/{now.strftime(format='%Y-%m-%d')}.log" #Create path for log
                                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How come `sudo` makes it throw an error like this?

Comment: The superuser `root` (which is who runs `sudo` commands) might be setup to use a different version of Python. Try running `sudo python --version` to check.

Comment: I'm running it within a virenv, but yeah, it throws two different versions. Sudo `/usr/bin/python`, "non-sudo" `path/to/virenv/bin/python`. Is there a way to make sudo use the activated virenv aswell ?

Comment: For most instances, running your command with `sudo` could indicate a design flaw. Why do you need to run as `sudo`? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: Since only sudo as access right for the logging file

Comment: I have an application logging to /var/log/syslog with a user that cannot read the file. So, sudo is _not_ required.